# Какая архитектура нейросети подойдет для временного ряда по нескольким данным?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, синтаксический-анализ, анализ-данных

Есть [dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ETDHjmlthS0cas-mVr72a7-HfiP2hyT_/view) со столбцами:

- НоменклатураКод( название)
- КоличествоОборот(сколько продано единиц товара всего за указанный период)
- СуммаОборот(всего продано по деньгам, то есть цена 1 единицы товара умножить на КоличествоОборот)
- Период(дата, какой-то день)

Как видно, на одну дату может быть несколько разных НоменклатураКод, то есть вариант временного ряда не подходит как для одного вида акций с постоянным изменением через равные промежутки времени. Какой выход?
Я предполагала, что на один товар НоменклатураКод строю отдельную сеть, а потом все сети соединяю в одну.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону prophet facebook, либо же смотрите на SARIMA

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [prophet facebook](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html), либо же смотрите на [SARIMA](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sarima-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/). Facebook сделал хорошую либу, которая неплохо обрабатывает цикличные данные, особенно, связанные с жизнидеятельностью человека за большие промежутки времени. Она из коробки умеет работать с праздниками и другими аналогичными свойствами данных. Но следует быть внимательным, если у Вас данные разреженные. Тогда, скорее всего, вы потерпите крах. В таком случае, лучше нагенерировать фичей руками и тренить [xgboost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) или другую деревянную модель. Посмотрите на [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/).

Что касается нейронок, то стоит просто гуглануть на [github python](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=time%20series%20neural%20network&type=Repositories) и [jupyter](https://github.com/search?l=Jupyter%20Notebook&q=time%20series%20neural%20network&type=Repositories). Но в случае разреженных данных, что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы можете получить примерно то же самое, что и в случае с prophet